# Discord.py printing category name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to make a command that will print all of the guild categories and channels.

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def category_test(ctx):

    for category in ctx.guild.categories:
        for channel in category.channels:
            print(category.name)
            print(channel.name)
```

Error:

```
File "c:\Users\My_user\Desktop\Py\tests.py", line 220, in category_test
    print(category.name)
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0142' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Are you sure all the category names are in unicode? That seems to be the error here

Comment: Yes I even created a new guild with only one channel named general. Still nothing :/.

Comment: It's not reproducible, works fine when I test it. The error is somewhere else